# Google earth separate application

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-pro, geo-platform

I am wondering is it possible to set up two google earths? I have a project that contains all the jobs our company done and I want this to act as an aid to estimators. It is a kml file. The problem is that this project will be forgetting about if it is used in the estimators everyday google earth as it will get lost in the mess of all there other kml files they open. Can a separate google earth be set up so that only my kml will be located there and nothing else?

Comment: Does it need to run at the same time? Or are you looking to set up something like different profiles? Also just to check, are you on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A client can only run a single instance of Google Earth.
Google Earth API (web client) used to be a workaround, but this is no longer supported.

It is worth mentioning that [ArcGIS Earth](http://www.esri.com/landing-pages/arcgis-earth), which seems to be Google Earth's successor, should have been launched "at the end of 2015". However, since ArcGIS Pro does not allow running two instance at the same time:

[image: ArcGIS Pro]

I doubt that ArcGIS Earth will.